# Cakephp missing helper file error

Tags: cakephp

I'm getting below error...I'm not sure what this means as I have included helper file in the view file...

Missing Helper File

```
Error: The helper file track/views/helpers/request_handler.php can not be found or does not exist.

Error: Create the class below in file: track/views/helpers/request_handler.php

<?php
class RequestHandlerHelper extends AppHelper {

}
?>
```

If you can let me know what this means that would be appreciated!

Thank you.
Jae

Comment: sure that you didnt mean the request handler component instead?...

Comment: Did you do any modification to your `config/bootstrap.php`, can you share? I was thinking you might have configured the "additional paths" wrongly, or whatever. The path start with "track" seems like either you have your bootstrap modified, or cake is trying to look for an helper in a plugin, hmm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you customized how your CakePHP works, this should apply to most cases:

**Checklist**

1. Make sure the helper file is created in `/app/views/helpers/request_handler.php`
2. Make sure the content of the `request_handler.php` looks like this:

   ```
   class RequestHandlerHelper extends AppHelper {
       var $name = 'RequestHandler';

       //bla....
   }
   ```
3. Make sure in the controller that renders the view has the helper array included

   ```
   class FancyController extends AppController {
       var $name = 'Fancy';
       var $helpers = array('RequestHandler');

       //bla....
   }
   ```
4. I think that's all :)

Cheers

Comment: Btw, I'm running CakePhp 3.0

Comment: Did you find any solution to your above problem? I am also facing similar issue when using WYSIWYG editor. With CakePHP 3, I think there is something extra required. Please respond.

Answer (score 3):

you have to include the helpers in the controller (app_controller if you want the helper to be available for views of all controller)

> ```
> var $helpers = array('Form', 'Html', 'YourHelper');
> ```

Comment: I don't know why but this code worked. Initially when not using any plugin, same line was giving error that cakephp3 does not support it. Anyways, thanks buddy! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using any version of CakePHP, just open the file core.php in the folder config and edit the line Configure::write('debug', 0); to Configure::write('debug', 2);

It will say the erro and how to create the file and where to put it.

Comment: I couldn't find that file on cakePHP 3.0

Comment: The `core.php` file has been replaced by `app.php` in Cake 3.X