# cakephp helper filename uppercase issue on linux server

Tags: php, linux, cakephp, cpanel

I'm working on cakephp 2.4, It works fine on xampp, when i uploaded to live server it says file not exists

```
Missing Helper
Error: stackHelper could not be found.

Error: Create the class stackHelper below in file: app/View/Helper/stackHelper.php

<?php
class stackHelper extends AppHelper {

}
```

I have helper with class name StackHelper on my pc, it wroks fine with StackHelper name.
but not works on live, 
if i lowercase stackHelper it works.

what the issue ?

Comment: Hey, this problem was already solved here: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6784345/3398757)

Comment: c != C - mind your casing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error: stackHelper could not be found.

There is a reference to the helper class using the wrong case: `stackHelper` - Check the helpers array in your controller classes (or read the stacktrace shown with the error - OR just search the code base for the case-sensitive string `stack`).

Unlike your local setup the file system on your server is case sensitive and for this reason it doesn't find the file and hence the class.